# Outlook: Auto-categorizing replied email based on original email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

EXAMPLE: I have tons of email in my Outlook inbox, but there's this conversation with Tom about the Report Status Update. We are emailing back and forth Replying back and forth. I categorized the original email as "Status Update" with a color of orange.

**I wish there was some way every time someone replies back to an email it auto-categorizes that new email based on what the original email's category is.**

So when Tom sends me updates about "Report Status Update" or "Standard Training" and Shelia sends me a reply on the fundraiser, it would auto-categorize the email based on what I categorized the original email, RATHER than me having to creating a rule for each email that was sent.

I would like for a macro to auto-categorize all replies based on the original sent email.

Comment: These folks claim to offer a plugin solution for Outlook 2010. I need something for 2011 on a Mac.... http://www.veranosoft.com/Categorize-Plus-Features.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Taglocity](http://www.taglocity.com/) add-in for Outlook has some great categorizing/tagging features. The free version will give you some handy tools for quickly categorizing email (the interface is far better than the one which comes built-in to Outlook, based on my experience over a few years of use). You can benefit more if the other people in the conversation also use Taglocity since the categories you attach to a conversation can be shared throughout the thread ([Using Taglocity 3 with Others](http://www.taglocity.com/groupSolutions.html)).

If you upgrade to the paid version of the add-in, you will also have some auto-categorizing features available.